# type hinting default values in classes

Tags: python, numpy, class, typing

How do I properly create type hints if the value isn't assigned yet.

For example:

```
class foo():
    def __init__():
        data: np.ndarray = None

    def load_data():
        data = np.loadtxt(...)
```

Now I obviously get a warning, that type ndarray is expected, and not None. What is an elegant solution to this? Do I just make up some ndarray like `data: np.ndarray = np.array([])`? That seams just wrong to me, and I'm sure there is a better way of doing it.

I still prefer the None version, because if there is an error with reading the numpy array, I will get an error like "can't calculate ... with type None". Then I imideatly know, it didn't read the file. Whereas, if the array is just empty, I might get weird errors, I don't understand.

**SOLUTION**:

Thanks to the commentators, pointing this out. The solution is importing Optional from typing, and then use `Optional[np.ndarray]` instead of `np.ndarray`

Comment: `from typing import Optional`?

Comment: Yes [`typing.Optional`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/typing.html#typing.Optional) seems the right choice

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `data: np.ndarray = np.empty([])`
Or if you know the dimension of the array, initialize it with its dimensions.
See [numpy.empty](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html) for more information.

Good Luck,
Ben

Comment: Ok, so my idea wasn't that wrong after all. Still, the problem with debugging still makes me wish, I could just call it None in the beginning, without my IDE complaining :D

Comment: You can also try `data: np.ndarray | None = None` maybe that would work for you :)

Comment: Yes, I have to update to python 3.10 though :D